# Why isn't lst.sort().reverse() valid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, methods

Per title. I do not understand why it is not valid. I understand that they mutate the object, but if you call the sort method, after it's done then you'd call the reverse method so it should be fine. Why is it then that I need to type lst.sort() then on the line below, lst.reverse()?

Edit: Well, when it's pointed out like that, it's a bit embarrassing how I didn't get it before. I literally recognize that it mutated the object and thus returns a None, but I suppose it didn't register that also meant that you can't reverse a None-type object.

Comment: `sort` sorts itself and does not return so `lst.sort()` becomes `NoneType`.

Comment: ... the error message is pretty clear. What did you not understand, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Search for “sorting in Python”, which will reveal list.sort() and sorted() options and explain differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call lst.sort(), it does not return anything, it changes the list itself.
So the result of lst.sort() is None, thus you try to reverse None which is impossible.

Comment: As a followup, what would be the equivalent one-liner of lst.sort().reverse() then? Something like x = reversed(sorted(lst)) ?

Comment: @bigbounty no, it wouldn't. `sorted(lst)` creates a new list, then you never save a reference to that list, but you call `.reverse()` on it. It is reversed, an since the list is no longer referenced, it is garbage collected. `x = sorted(lst).reverse()` will result in `x == None`

Comment: @accountaccountaccount `x = list(reversed(sorted(lst)))` Or in this *particular* case, you probably just want `lst.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: Yeah, if you need the original list also, then it won't work

Comment: @bigbounty um, it just *doesn't work at all like that*. Go ahead and try it. You can't get the sorted, reversed list.

Comment: Yes, correct I tried it, thanks for correcting me. The reference will be lost. Good learning

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why the need for list again on reversed sorted?

Comment: @accountaccountaccount because `reversed` returns a `reversed` object, not a list, but an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, `lst.sort()` does not return the list sorted. It modifies itself.

```py
>>> lst = [3,1,2,0]
>>> lst
[3, 1, 2, 0]
>>> lst.sort().reverse()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse'
>>>
```

Since `lst.sort()` doesn't return anything, Python automatically returns `None` for you. Since `None` doesn't have a `reverse` method, you get an error.

```py
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst.reverse()
>>> lst
[3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try reversing the list while sorting Like

```
lst.sort( reverse=True )
```

Comment: i did not know this.